# Calling constructor of a class from type object in dart

Tags: flutter, class, dart, oop, constructor

I'm getting an error like

> The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked.

Is there any workaround to achieve this I have different classes being returned from a map according to the key.

```
void main() {
  Map<String, Type> map = {'user': User};
  Type T = map['user']!;
  User a = T(5);
  print(a.id);
}

class User {
  User(this.id);
  final int id;
}
```

[image: This is a basic map from which I expect a type to be returned based on key and want to create a an object of the returned type]

Comment: You cannot call static methods, factory constructors or constructors on types in Dart since Dart have no way of statically guarantee that such a thing is part of a type since subclasses to a type is not forced to have the same static methods, factory constructors or constructors. So we cannot ensure that a subclass to `User`, in this example, would have a constructor which takes only one argument.

Comment: @julemand101 well is there a workaround that could serve my use case??

Comment: Depends really of what you are looking for. Your example is kinda basic so I am not sure what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @julemand101, I have edited the question with a snippet. it basically returns a type and I want it to be used something like
`Series_Type_Mapper['multiLine'](name; 'series1')`. which should be the equivalent of `LineSeries(name: 'series1')`

Comment: Does all your types share a common interface? Also, why not just call the constructor directly instead of `Series_Type_Mapper['multiLine']`?

Comment: I just try to understand what we can say is common for entries in `Series_Type_Mapper` like e.g. do we know we can always just create the object just by providing the same number and types of arguments? And what kind of guarantee you want about the returned type? Do we need to cast the type afterwards? Remember that we should try make our Dart code as type safe as possible.